# CSOM: Loading nested property fails, but data is being transmitted - why?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

**Short description of my problem**

I'm requesting certain properties from SharePoint via CSOM but when accessing them I get the dreaded `PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException`. But looking at the transmitted data using Fiddler I can see the requested data has been transmitted.

**More details about each step**

Complete code of repro console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var authMgr = new AuthenticationManager();
    using (var ctx = authMgr.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev", "admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com", "tree desk wall magma core"))
    {
        var web = ctx.Web;
        ctx.Load(web, w => w.RoleAssignments);
        ctx.LoadQuery(web.RoleAssignments.Include(b => b.Member.Title));
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve `web.RoleAssignments[n].Member.Title` for all RoleAssignments. Executing this I can see in Fiddler that the title is included in the response:

[image]

But when I try to access the `Title` in the Immediate window of Visual Studio I get the `PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException`:

```
web.RoleAssignments[0].Member.Title
'web.RoleAssignments[0].Member.Title' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233079
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "The property or field 'Title' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."
    Source: "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime"
    StackTrace: "   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject.CheckUninitializedProperty(String propName)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Principal.get_Title()"
    TargetSite: {Void CheckUninitializedProperty(System.String)}
```

It's like the CSOM library fails to propagate the `Title` information it received into the `Member` property. Is this a restriction of CSOM? But why transmit the information in the first place? Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing it wrong. It seems like CSOM does not aggregate data of related queries. (This was my expectation.)

The corrected code the get the `Title` property is:

```
var web = ctx.Web;
ctx.Load(web.RoleAssignments, a => a.Include(b => b.Member.Title));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now `web.RoleAssignments[n].Member.Title` succeeds.

Doh.